# Why are variables defined inside loop are accessible outside?

Tags: python, scope

```
for i in range(1, 10):
   a =10
print(a)
```

It is giving me the output: `10`
Expected output: `Name is not defined`
Can anyone please explain?

Comment: That's just how scope works in python

Comment: Which scope we will refer to it ? Global, local or any other . ? can u please explain ? @Lagerbaer